# how to make this code working in mobile view of blogger?

Tags: html, loops, blogger

This conditional code is works well when viewed from a desktop browser, but I would like this to work as a mobile site as well. Please suggest any modifications required.

Step- 1 below`</b:skin>` pasted the following code-

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url !=
&quot;http://yourblog.blogspot.com/search/label/Label&quot;'>
<style>
#Gadgetid{
display: none;
}
</style>
</b:if>
```

Step-2 Below`<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>` pasted the following code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;index&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;Label&quot;'>
<style>
#gadgetid{
display: block !important;
}
</style>
</b:if>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use @media queries to add or remove anything from mobile sites. Media queries allowing you to customize site completely on any specific device or dimension of screen.

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/